# Ubuntu cannot boot

Tags: 12.04, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I've Ubuntu 12.04 installed along with windows 7. After trying to update the Geforce driver on Ubuntu (already updated on windows), Ubuntu fails to boot. It will only give me a black screen and ask for log in user name and password and stays on the black screen.

I've tried to fix it from a boot repair disk, which had generated a long report and then told me that Wubi.exe is not found.

How can I retrieve my [revious installation, or fix it please? If not possible what is the best procedure to re install Ubuntu without affecting the partitions please.

Regards,

Comment: When it asks you for username/pwd, does it accept it and boot to terminal?

Comment: yes, it does. I'll be logged in and can see the documents as well, but can't access them.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with booting, sometime updating graphics driver causes this problem.

try `ctrl+alt+F1` if you get a terminal screen, then you can try resetting `unity`

```
unity --reset
```

if this doesn't help then try to purge unity and reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to reset the unity and got the following message: WARNING: No display variable set, setting it to: 0 - Process (1768) Gconf-warning **: client failed to connect to the D-Bus Daemon:  //bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error:  X11 initialization failed    WARNING: Environment incorrect: No D-Bus Daemon running. I also tried to reinstall it but it showed me a message telling that it exists and in final version. Help is highly appreciated please.

Comment: if you are using proprietary driver then try to remove it and install open source driver. check this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: Thanks again. Most of the instruction is through the GUI, however, using the jockey command failed for no authority reason. I still appreciate if you can help, noting I'm not familiar with Ubuntu commands, but can follow instructions. Thank you again and hope this issue will be solved. Regards.

Comment: you need root permissions to do that, type `sudo su` then press enter and then enter your password, you will see # sign instead of $.

Comment: Well Done. Highly appreciated.

Comment: **Deepak**, you should use&recommend `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su` to avoid corruption by user's env vars. (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Special_notes_on_sudo_and_shells )

Comment: @LovinBuntu thanks for the link, i never understood the difference b/w them